# the number of the output unit and the loss function in binary classification network

Tags: binary, neural-network, classification

Say I have a binary classification task, and I build a neural network to do this.
There are two different framework to choose in which the first is the network has one output unit indicating the probability belonging to one of the class, thus I can use the binary cross-entropy to compute the loss, the second is the network has two output units indicating the probabilities belonging to the two classes separately, also I can use the softmax cross-entropy to compute the loss.
Some suggests to use the first option, my confusion is that what the pros and cons of the two options are, and what the severest problem is if I choose the second framework? Can anyone explain this in detail to me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use one output unit then you should understand that you are choosing strictly between two classes. If the probability is high enough then your netwrok chooses class A, otherwise it chooses class B. If you have two output units your network may produce rather low probability for both your units so you will end up with neither A nor B. You should choose among those two approaches depending on what is the real system you're trying to model with your network.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Alexey R.I don't quite understand your point. Even the network has two output units,say y = [x1,x2], and I can apply softmax function to this to get the probabilities, and what you mean your network may produce rather low probability is not always true. If the two outputs differs a lot, I still can get a relatively high probability of one class.

Comment: Yes, but how would you treat the results if they are both low? In one output unit network you would not have such the problem.

Comment: In this situation, it suggests that the network can not predict the class for sure, which is equivalent to the network with one output unit when it outputs around 0.5.

Comment: Yes and no. When you have one output you should set up a threshold that would say that the network is sure anough to assigne your input to one of your classes. If this threashold is not hit then you accept your input to belong to class A, otherwise it would belong to class B. There are no other options, either class A or class B (no both of them and no neither of them). When you have two outputs you can extend the way how you would treat the results.